# Want to have 'all photos' with edits (develop settings) on new phone without sync option

Tags: lightroom, adobe, mobile, android-app

I have lightroom mobile 6.2.1 version (unlocked) on old phone with over 162 images under 'All photos'. Sync option is disabled for obvious reasons.

I need to transfer this data to new phone with latest lightroom mobile version so that those images  show under 'all photos' with edits done  (exposure changes, colour change etc) visible.

I tried :

* Transferred CarouselDocuments folder to similar location under lightroom directory in new phone. * Transperred 'Originals' and 'xmp_develop' folder likewise.

But, upon opening lightroom I couldn't see any image under album.

Comment: What are the "obvious" reasons for which sync options are disabled?

Comment: So as to keep it working without any hindrance I guess

Comment: Why wouldn't it work if sync option were enabled?

Comment: I haven't bought subscription but could use all premium features.